# Paperclip displaying multiple 'missing image' tags on edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip

So I have an object that has multiple photos (through use of a model called asset). I'm using paperclip to upload the photos and it's working fine.  On my show page I call

```
<li class="grid_3">Photos:<br /></li>
<% @address.assets.each do |asset| %>
  <li class='grid_3'><%= image_tag(asset.photo.url, size: '100x100') %></li>
<% end %>
```

and the photos display perfectly.  when I click on the edit page:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :assets do |asset| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'asset_fields', :locals => { :f => asset } %>
<% end %>
```

the partial is rendered:

```
<div class='nested-fields'>
  <%= f.file_field :photo %>  
  <% unless f.object.new_record? %>
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
    <% @address.assets.each do |asset| %>
      <li class='grid_3'><%= image_tag(asset.photo.url, size: '100x100')  %></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

at this point the photos each show up 3 times along with an extra image tag with a 'missing' photo placeholder.  I would say I've tried different things but I just don't see what is wrong with the code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `simple_fields_for` behaves the same as `fields_for`... the call to `f.simple_fields_for :assets` is a loop already. It loops over `f.object.assets` and renders the contents of the block once for each item found using the `asset` form generator (it may be a little less confusing to call that block variable `asset_form`, by the way). So since you're then rendering a partial that also renders all of the assets for the `@address` that's why you get each image 3 times.

Comment: ok so that makes sense, but why then do i still get this pseudo-object next to my photo when I click on edit? it's a missing photo placeholder. there is only one asset as confirmed in the console, yet this placeholder is there.

Comment: @mano26, I'd need to see updated code and maybe a screenshot of the issue. But it sounds like you're saying that the `image_tag` src url isn't loading a confirmed asset upload? Did you confirm on the console that `asset.photo.url` returns a path to a working image as expected?

Comment: no, the asset loads up fine.   on the show page it shows the asset.  on the edit page it shows the asset plus another image tag with a missing placeholder